# Find & Remove a generic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Obviously this is a generic example that I will have to adapt to generic situations.

I want to remove a DOM element that has no ID or classes. I can use many methods, but I would like to know if I can do it without adding classes (for example), if JQuery can do this kind of match.

**Doing something wrong, or is not it possible?**

Thanks

---

*Sorry for the first release of this question, I was overwriting the div Result*

The result in `$newTest` is that it has not removed `$last`, the last paragraph.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $last = $('#test').children().last(); // Get a generic element
  var $newTest = $('#test').clone(); // Clone my DOM elements

  $newTest.find($last).remove(); 
  // Find and remove the element!
  // This does not work!

  $('#result').html($newTest.html() + '<hr>' + $last.html());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <p>freddy</p>
  <p>fred</p>
  <p>freddyx</p>
  <p>freddy</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear how you intend to identify this "generic element"? Whats your selection criteria

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems to be working? Try changing the value of your first and last `<p>` tag as it may be confusing you.

Comment: But if you want to remove the element from the DOM, why you need the `clone()`? Probably I'm missing something, but can't you just go with `$('#test').children().last().remove();`?

Comment: @A.Iglesias  The context is different, this will be integrated into a plugin that loop all the children of any DOM element, I don't know what it will contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue in what you're trying to do lies with .clone()

> [From the docs, .clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)
>
> **Description: Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.**

The key word here is **deep copy** meaning that everything in `$newTest` is different than `#test`. AFAIK, that means the variable `$last` you're saving as a pointer can't be found in `$newTest`. The `$last` element doesn't exist there.

**Potential solution?**

I don't know if this would work given your use-case, but since you have already some arbitrary selector you could save that selector and use `eval()` to apply that selector to the cloned object:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $last = $($('#test').children().last()); // Get a generic element
  
  var selector = '.children().last()';
  
  var $newTest = $('#test').clone(); // Clone my DOM elements
 
  $newTest.find(eval('$newTest' + selector)).remove();
  // Find and remove the element!
  // This does not work, $newTest is empty!

  $('#result').html($newTest);
  $('#result2').html('<hr>' + $last.html());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <p>freddy</p>
  <p>fred</p>
  <p>freddyx</p>
  <p>freddy</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="result">

</div>
<hr>
<div id="result2">

</div>
```

Comment: You're right! I could `$('#test').find($last).remove();` and obviously it works. Nothing to say...

Comment: to make it works try to add something like data attributes and get its value search for that inside the new list. The answer is right - with clone you'll get 2 different objects

Comment: Updated with an idea for a solution, not sure if it would work in your situation though.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for your suggestion! It will be a bit more complicated, it will be a recursive function, so I will probably assign classes as a reference and at the end I remove all classes. Thanks !! :)